# Getting 404 error on homepage only

Tags: errors, 404-error

I keep getting an error message at www.e-z-university.com/blog my blog page. Everything seems to be working fine except www.e-z-university.com/blog I can view pages, posts, everything but the blog's home page and I am wondering why.

here is the htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ./blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: can you show your .htaccess file?

Comment: I really need some help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using Nginx which is very likely your issue. Nginx has a great writeup on what you need to do to with WordPress:
http://wiki.nginx.org/Wordpress

Other useful resources:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695387/nginx-404-not-found-page-for-permalinks
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255446/wordpress-3-0-nginx-permalink-404-problem
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nginx-compatibility/other_notes/

Let me know if this works!

Cheers~